# OutputStream already Obtained

Tags: jsp, exception, servlets, jfreechart, outputstream

I'm using the JFree chart.
Then finally i get the exception when using the

### Java File:

```
ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(response.getOutputStream(), chart,
                       1150, 450);
```

### Jsp File:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportPost.do?method=generateParetoInstanceBasedChart" alt="Graph" width="100%" height="450"  border="0"/></br>
```

### Server:

IBM Webshpere 6.0.1

The chart works fine. But the console it shows the error

```
[11/22/12 18:31:28:243 IST] 0000002f ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: /jsp/layout/layout.jsp. Exception thrown : java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.getWriter(SRTServletResponse.java:601)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:196)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flush(JspWriterImpl.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:893)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:465)
    at com.ibm._jsp._layout._jspx_meth_tiles_insert_0(_layout.java:568)
    at com.ibm._jsp._layout._jspService(_layout.java:162)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:87)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1146)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1087)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:588)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:525)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:232)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:639)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doInclude(RequestProcessor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:292)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:271)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:332)
    at com.ford.it.strutscore.context.ScTilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(ScTilesRequestProcessor.java:863)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:232)
    at com.ford.it.strutscore.context.ScTilesRequestProcessor.processRequest(ScTilesRequestProcessor.java:199)
    at com.ford.it.strutscore.context.ScTilesRequestProcessor.process(ScTilesRequestProcessor.java:143)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1146)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1087)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
    at com.ford.it.persistencecore.context.PcRequestContextFilter.doFilter(PcRequestContextFilter.java:153)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ford.mpl.supergweb.context.I18NUserProfileFilter.doFilterChain(I18NUserProfileFilter.java:139)
    at com.ford.mpl.supergweb.context.I18NUserProfileFilter.doFilter(I18NUserProfileFilter.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ford.it.context.RequestContextFilter.doFilter(RequestContextFilter.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ford.mpl.supergweb.context.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:50)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:588)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:525)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:764)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)

---- Begin backtrace for Nested Throwables
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.getWriter(SRTServletResponse.java:601)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:196)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flush(JspWriterImpl.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:893)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:465)
    at com.ibm._jsp._layout._jspx_meth_tiles_insert_0(_layout.java:568)
    at com.ibm._jsp._layout._jspService(_layout.java:162)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:87)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1146)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1087)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:588)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:525)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:232)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:639)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doInclude(RequestProcessor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:292)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:271)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:332)
    at com.ford.it.strutscore.context.ScTilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(ScTilesRequestProcessor.java:863)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:232)
    at com.ford.it.strutscore.context.ScTilesRequestProcessor.processRequest(ScTilesRequestProcessor.java:199)
    at com.ford.it.strutscore.context.ScTilesRequestProcessor.process(ScTilesRequestProcessor.java:143)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1146)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1087)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
    at com.ford.it.persistencecore.context.PcRequestContextFilter.doFilter(PcRequestContextFilter.java:153)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ford.mpl.supergweb.context.I18NUserProfileFilter.doFilterChain(I18NUserProfileFilter.java:139)
    at com.ford.mpl.supergweb.context.I18NUserProfileFilter.doFilter(I18NUserProfileFilter.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ford.it.context.RequestContextFilter.doFilter(RequestContextFilter.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ford.mpl.supergweb.context.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:50)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:588)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:525)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:764)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)


[11/22/12 18:31:28:368 IST] 0000002f SRTServletRes W   WARNING: Cannot set status. Response already committed.
[11/22/12 18:31:28:368 IST] 0000002f SRTServletRes W   WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.)
```

### JavaPage:

```
try
        {
            CategoryDataset dataset1 = createDataSetForInstanceBasedChart();
             String instancesCountLabelName = I18nMessageUtil.getMessage(CommonUtil.getLocale(), "label.reports.wdid.instcnt");
             JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                    "",       // chart title
                    "",               // domain axis label
                    instancesCountLabelName,                  // range axis label
                    dataset1,                  // data
                    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
                    true,                     // include legend
                    true,                     // tooltips?
                    false                     // URLs?
                );

                // NOW DO SOME OPTIONAL CUSTOMISATION OF THE CHART...

                // set the background color for the chart...
                chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
                CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
                plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);

                /*CategoryDataset dataset2 = createDataset2();
                plot.setDataset(1, dataset2);
                plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(1, 1);*/

                CategoryItemRenderer renderer1 = plot.getRenderer();
               renderer1.setSeriesItemLabelGenerator(0,new CategoryItemLabelGenerator() {

                    public String generateRowLabel(final CategoryDataset arg0, final int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }

                    public String generateLabel(final CategoryDataset dataset1,final int series,final int category) {
                        String result = null;
                        //CHAPTER 12. ITEM LABELS 91
                        final Number value = dataset1.getValue(series, category);
                        if (value != null) {
                        final double v = value.doubleValue();
                        if (v > 0) {
                        result = value.toString(); // could apply formatting here
                        }
                        }
                        return result;
                        }


                    public String generateColumnLabel(final CategoryDataset arg0, final int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }
                });
               renderer1.setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(0,true);
               System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++renderer1" +renderer1);
                BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
                renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
                renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(0,Color.BLACK);
                renderer.setDrawBarOutline(true);
                renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(0.02);
                renderer.setSeriesPaint(0,new Color(170, 0, 85));          
                System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!renderer" +renderer);
                CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
                domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(.6));  
                domainAxis.setLabelFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14));
                domainAxis.setTickLabelFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14));
                System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@domainAxis" +domainAxis);
                /*String numOfSupplrs = I18nMessageUtil.getMessage(CommonUtil.getLocale(), "label.rateElement.history.numOfSupplrs");
                ValueAxis axis2 = new NumberAxis(numOfSupplrs);
                axis2.setLabelFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14));    
                axis2.setTickLabelFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 14));
                //if(!this.isValueDataZeros)
                    //axis2.setRange(0,13);
                plot.setRangeAxis(1, axis2);*/

                NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
               // if(!this.isNumberDataZeros)
                    //rangeAxis.setRange(0,90);
               //rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(1)); 
               rangeAxis.setLabelFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14));
               rangeAxis.setTickLabelFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 14));

                /*LineAndShapeRenderer renderer2 = new LineAndShapeRenderer();
                renderer2.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLUE);
                Start 
                renderer2.setSeriesItemLabelGenerator(0,new CategoryItemLabelGenerator() {

                    public String generateRowLabel(final CategoryDataset arg0, final int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }

                    public String generateLabel(final CategoryDataset dataset1,final int series,final int category) {
                        String result = null;
                        //CHAPTER 12. ITEM LABELS 91
                        final Number value = dataset1.getValue(series, category);
                        if (value != null) {
                        final double v = value.doubleValue();
                        if (v > 0) {
                        result = value.toString(); // could apply formatting here
                        }
                        }
                        return result;
                        }


                    public String generateColumnLabel(final CategoryDataset arg0, final int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }
                });
               renderer2.setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(0,true);*/
                /* End */
                //plot.setRenderer(1, renderer2);
                plot.setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);
                System.out.println("#########################plot" +plot);
                ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(response.getOutputStream(), chart,
                       1150, 450);

                log.exiting(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);
        }
        catch(Exception writeInstanceBasedParetoChartException)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception in writeInstanceBasedParetoChartException: "+writeInstanceBasedParetoChartException.getMessage());
        }
```

### What i want:

How can i avoid the error in the console ? Please Give me the suggestion. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you show the code of these stream operations in both java and JSP?

Comment: ok ashwin..i will add in the two mins..

Comment: Where are you initializing the outputstream and inputstream in this?

Comment: i'm not intialized anywhere.Is that mandatory to intialized

Comment: Is this the only place where you are using response.getOutputStream() in the java file? - ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(response.getOutputStream(), chart,
                       1150, 450);   Or are you using it more than one time?

Comment: wait i check and let you know that

Comment: i'm not using anywhere...until the java file

Comment: @ashwin ,did u got the issue

Comment: no, but generally you get such an error when you have two instances of the outputstream. I am also not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Read http://www.coderanch.com/t/55147/Struts/OutputStream-obtained-error-generating-pdf.
I encountered the same problem, but in my case I didn't need JSP/Java page as response.

I used:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);    
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

IOUtils.copy(inputStream, out);    
inputStream.close();

out.flush();    
out.close();

response.flushBuffer();

return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

In handling a servlet request one can only once get the OutputStream (for binary data) or Writer (for text).

The error indicates that a second attempt was made. This could typically happen in a JSP when the output is doubled: your binary image data, and the JSP itself; for instance a newline after the final `%>`.

Here it seems that a tag is wanted to be written. Maybe a return is missing.
Especially take care to write an HTTP header `setContentType("application/png")` and such.